# VS Code debugger is inconsistent while hitting breakpoints

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, next.js

I want to set up my VS Code debugger to debug my **Next.js** app. My `launch.json` contains the below settings:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "port": 9229,
      "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "!**/node_modules/**"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I also added the debug script to my `packege.json`:

```
"debug": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev"
```

First, I run `npm run debug` in my terminal, then I launch the debugger in the VS Code **Run and Debug** tab. The debugger is attached, but when I start adding breakpoints, some of them work properly (the dot indicating the breakpoint is red and the app stops when the breakpoint is hit), but most of them are ignored despite the red indicator. There're also some unbound breakpoints.

I spent a few days figuring this out with no effect. I really look forward to  moving past console-logging for debugging purposes.

**VS Code version: 1.57.0**